# Hide more worksheets along with Admin Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, show-hide

I have made a user login & logout.
If Admin logs in, it shows admin sheet.
If non-admin logs in, the admin sheet does not show up.

I want to hide more sheets along with Admin sheet.

Code to hide Admin sheet when non-admin logs in:

```vb
Private Sub okbtn_Click()

Dim Wksht As Worksheet

If Sheet11.Range("B6").Value = True Then

    Sheet11.Range("B7").Value = Sheet11.Range("B4").Value 'Set Current User

    Loginfrm.Hide

    For Each Wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Wksht.Name = "Admin" Then

            If Sheet11.Range("B8") = "Yes" Then 'Admin

                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
 
            Else:

                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

            End If

        Else: 'Not Admin

            Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible

        End If

    Next Wksht

    Sheet11.Range("B4,B5").ClearContents

Else:

    MsgBox "Please enter correct Username & Password"

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `Select Case` instead of `If Wksht.Name = "Admin"`. Something Like this:

```
Select Case Wksht.Name
    Case "Admin", "sheet_a", "sheet_b"
        ' do some stuff if it's one of the above sheets
        ' ***
        ' ***
    Case Else
        ' do other stuff if it's not one of them
        ' ***
        ' ***
End Select
```

You can add addittional cases too.

Comment: Thank you, my dumb brain finally figured out how to use Select Case